# Reporting Server Idle Connection Timeouts

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and idle connections are timing out after 20 minutes. Where do I change this so they don't time out at all?

Comment: What happens when it times out? Doesn't SSRS just open a new one?

Comment: Yes, but it just adds to the waiting and delay to the process.. Time is money in our business.

Comment: SSRS is a website, so have you configured the site to stay alive longer than 20 minutes?